# Regex to get folders and file name parts of a path

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse a partial URL path into 3 groups.

- Group 1 - Jobs or Docs.
- Group 2 - The folder path (or empty if the file is directly under Jobs or Docs).
- Group 3 - The file name (or empty if only a folder path is specified).

e.g.

- /Jobs/STU0001/Folder1/Sub Folder A/File Name.txt - should match on all groups.
- /Docs/Folder 2 - should match on groups 1 and 2.
- /Docs/Another File.doc - should match on groups 1 and 3.

I've tried the following (and other slight variations of the same) but just can't get one pattern to suit all the possible inputs.

`^/?(Jobs|Docs)/(.*)/(.+\..+)?$` - Works for 1, not 2 or 3

`^/?(Jobs|Docs)/(.*)/?(.+\..+)?$` - Works for 2, not 1 or 3

For info:

- File names will always have an extension (and therefore a full stop/period).
- Folder names will never have a full stop/period in their name.

Comment: Why not use standard methods? `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)` to get just the file name, `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file)` to get the folder information. You can then split the latter by `\\` if you want the parts.

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Comment: @AlekDepler Regex is very useful in a boatload of cases. Just not in ones that can be solved faster and more reliably with onboard methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one:

```
^/(Docs|Jobs)(?:/([^.\n]*))?(?:/([^/\n]+\.[^/\n]+))?$
```

Broken apart:

`^` Start of line

`/` Initial slash

`(Docs|Jobs)` Captures the first directory

`(?:/([^.\n]*))?` Matches a slash and captures the folder part.

`(?:/([^/\n]+\.[^/\n]+))?` Matches a slash and captures the filename part.

`$` End of string

The directory part can basically contain anything excepts periods and line feeds.

The filename part must contain three parts - 1) a filename **not** containing slashes or line feeds, 2) a period, and 3) an extension **not** containing slashes or line feeds.

Both are optional.

[See it here at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%2f%28Docs%7cJobs%29%28%3f%3a%2f%28%5b%5e.%5cn%5d*%29%29%3f%28%3f%3a%2f%28%5b%5e%5c%2f%5cn%5d%2b%5c.%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b%29%29%3f%24&i=%2fJobs%2fSTU0001%2fFolder1%2fSub+Folder+A%2fFile+Name.txt%0d%0a%2fDocs%2fFolder+2%0d%0a%2fDocs%2fAnother+File.doc&o=m).

[See a better visual illustration here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SWQEPG/3).

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `\/?(Jobs|Docs)(?:\/(.+)(?=\/|$))?(?:\/?([^\.]+\.[a-z]+))?`

**Output**:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-48    `/Jobs/STU0001/Folder1/Sub Folder A/File Name.txt`
Group 1.    1-5     `Jobs`
Group 2.    6-34    `STU0001/Folder1/Sub Folder A`
Group 3.    35-48   `File Name.txt`

Match 2
Full match  49-71   `/Docs/Another File.doc`
Group 1.    50-54   `Docs`
Group 3.    55-71   `Another File.doc`

Match 3
Full match  72-86   `/Docs/Folder 2`
Group 1.    73-77   `Docs`
Group 2.    78-86   `Folder 2`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZREPnu/1)